# Is $k[[x,x^{-1}]]$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I wonder if the formal power series ring $k[[x,x^{-1}]]$ is a field or not.
I tried to show that every element $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i x^i$ has an inverse but failed. I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: This is not a ring! What **is** true is that the field of Laurent series with **finite** principal part is a field. In fact, it is the fraction field of $k[\![x]\!]$.

Comment: ... and it can also be written as $k[[x]][x^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not even a ring. Consider the product
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\cdots)$$,
whose constant term cannot be computed.